# Spring 2.5 + quartz java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/JobDetail

Tags: java, spring, maven, quartz-scheduler

I have an issue with quartz library. I'm using it with spring 2.5:

```
<bean id="reminderBean" class="com.mail.timexis.ReminderBean">
        <property name="mailSender">
            <ref local="timexisMailSender" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobDetail"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="reminderBean" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
        <!-- run every morning at 6 AM -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="* * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And when i run tomcat it cannot instantiate "jobDetail" bean because it can't see JobDetail class used by MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean class `( Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/JobDetail)`

Maven downloads the jars and i can see it under MavenDependencies and I can find the JobDetail class.

I think it's something with the compatibility of spring 2.5 and quartz. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the dependency to `spring-context-support` ?

It contains the `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` which seems to be missing according to the stacktrace.

Comment: Did you open the war file, and looked at the missing class ?

Comment: problem solved: I have 2 projects and the first use the second as dependecy. So the one that builds the war dont have the jar-s.